# How to overlap nonblocking communication

Tags: c++, c, performance, parallel-processing, mpi

I know that Nonblocking communication is not blocking the code, such as MPI_Isend will send the data immediately. But when we have some all-to-all communication and we need to read this data we need to use MPI_Wait to get the data first.

for all-to-all communication the first thing that is coming in my mind is something like: (it is a real code)

```
1- initialise the MPI, getting the rank and size... 
2- creating the data or read the first data from file
3- in a for loop, we need to send the data from all ranks to the other, by MPI_Isend or Evan MPI_Bcast
4- finalise the MPI
```

for writing the for loop, we need to use MPI_Wait for both sending and receiving.
My question is how we can use overlap in nonblocking.

I want to use two times MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv in each iteration loop to overlap some the computation from the first receiving data and meanwhile do another send and receive, but this approach needs 4 waiting, Is there any algorithm for overlapping the nonblocking communications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that None-blocking communication is not blocking the code, such
> as MPI_Isend will send the data immediately.

This is not accurate the data is not send immediately. Let me explain in more detail:

[MPI_Irecv](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Irecv.html) and [MPI_Isend](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Isend.html) are nonblocking communication routines, therefore one needs to use the [MPI_Wait](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Wait.html) (or use [MPI_Test](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Test.html) to test for the completion of the request) to ensure that the message is completed, and that the data in the send/receive buffer can be again **safely** manipulated.

The nonblocking here means one does not wait for the data to be read and sent; rather the data is **immediately made available to be read and sent.** That does not imply, however, that the data is immediately sent. If it were, there would not be a need to call MPI_Wait.

> But when we have some all-to-all communication and we need to read
> this data we need to use MPI_Wait to get the data first.

You need to call `MPI_Wait` (or `MPI_Test`) in call communication types 1 to 1, 1 to n, and so on not just in all-to-all. Calling MPI_Wait is not about getting the data first, but rather that during the `MPI_Isend` the content of the buffer (e.g., the array of ints) has to be read and sent; In the meantime, one can overlap some computation with the ongoing process, however this computation cannot change (or read) the contend of the send/recv buffer. Then one calls the `MPI_Wait` **to ensure that from that point onwards the data send/recv can be safely read/modified without any issues.**

> I want to use two times MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv in each iteration loop
> to overlap some the computation from the first receiving data and
> meanwhile do another send and receive, but this approach needs 4
> waiting, Is there any algorithm for overlapping the nonblocking
> communications?

Whenever possible just use in build communication routines they are likely more optimized than one would able to optimized. What you have described fits perfectly the MPI routine [MPI_Ialltoall](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Ialltoall.html):

> Sends data from all to all processes in a nonblocking way